# Cypress and TS: Unable to click button without using wait()

Tags: typescript, click, cypress

In the following piece of markup/code, I find that Cypress is unable to click a button unless I add a wait(1000) - 1000 is the lowest I've found to be working - before attempting the click.

If I don't use the wait, and instead use should('be.visible') on the button element, the Cypress runner shows the click() as executed, with no errors, but it never happens. I can manually click the button before the test times out, and it will continue.

Markup (it's an Angular application):

```
<div class="hb-knappesamling noprint"><div class="hb-knappesamling-gruppe hb-knappesamling-gruppe--navigasjon">
<!--bindings={
 "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
  }-->
 <div class="hb-knappesamling-element">
  <button hb-knapp="" translate="" type="submit" ng-reflect-id="sendTilSignering" ng-reflect- type="submit" ng-reflect-variant="FREMHEVET" 
ng-reflect-translate="" id="sendTilSignering" data-e2e-selector="sendTilSignering" class="hb-knapp hb-knapp--fremhevet ">
  <!--bindings={
   "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
  -->
  <!--bindings={}-->
   <span class="hb-knapp-tekst" translate="" ng-reflect-translate="">Send til signering</span>
   <!--bindings={
    "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
    }-->
    <!--bindings={}-->
  </button>
 </div>
 <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
  }-->
```

The test code:

```
cy.get('[data-e2e-selector=sendTilSignering]').should('be.visible');
cy.get('[data-e2e-selector=sendTilSignering]').click({force:true);
```

(Same result when using the id as with the data-e2e-selector above.)

Cypress runner output:

[image]

No errors, but nothing happens. If I click the button manually, the test continues.

Or, if I add a wait(1000) just before trying the click, it also works.

Things I've tried:

1. Using {force:true} on the click - allways the first thing to try - with no help.
2. cy.get('[data-e2e-selector=sendTilSignering]').trigger("click"). No help.
3. Executing the click() command two times. No help. Also, the button click will do a submit which should only be done once.
4. Using .should('be.visible').and('be.enabled') as per Alapan Das' suggestion below. No help.

Comment: How about you add two assertions - `cy.get('[data-e2e-selector=sendTilSignering]').should('be.visible').and('be.enabled')` ?

Comment: +1 to Alapan's suggestion -- is there something in the HTML that is preventing the button from being clicked?

Comment: I don't see anything. I'll try adding more of the markup, but since the button is immediately clickable manually - in the test runner - while the test is waiting for the next element to be clickable, I cannot see how?

Comment: Good idea about chaining be.visible and be.enabled. Didn't work, though.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will fix it, but try using `.realClick()` from [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I installed and set up cypress-real-event. But sadly, realClick() made no difference.

Comment: It looks like the event handler is not attached to the button at the time you click. See [When Can The Test Start?](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2018/02/05/when-can-the-test-start/) for a work around. But frankly, I'd stick with `cy.wait()`.

Comment: cy.wait() is pretty reliable, at least. Better than pure work-arounds. But there is something lacking in a commercial test automation technology when there's no way to effectively wait for a button to be clickable. This worked better in Selenium, as I remember it.